# How to remove fill in excel table (restore default background color ) - VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a simple table and want to remove fill (restore default background color) using VBA.

This is my code:

```
Function cleanTable(tableName As String)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim table As ListObject: Set table = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects(tableName)

    For i = 1 To table.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
        table.ListRows(i).Range.Interior.Pattern = 0
    Next i
End Function
```

But I am receiving the error:

> Application defined or object defined error

And have no idea how to solve it.

Will be really thankful for your support

Comment: There is no need to loop through the rows here - just work with the entire `DataBodyRange`

Comment: Do you want to change the `TableStyle`? As @vityata screenshots, show, your code removes the pattern from a table, not the "fill."

Answer (score 1):

Using almost your code, starting with this:

[image]

I get this:

[image]

Without getting any error. How are you calling the function exactly? This is what I have used:

```
Sub TestMe()
    cleanTable "myTable"
End Sub

Function cleanTable(tableName As String)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim table As ListObject
    Set table = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).ListObjects(tableName)
    For i = 1 To table.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
        table.ListRows(i).Range.Interior.Pattern = 0
    Next i
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reset to the default background with:

```
Range("A1").Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
```

...if that's what you're asking

Answer (score 0):

```
tablename.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorWhite
```

worked for me